# Why is $_POST empty when sending data using fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I am trying to just sent some POST data via fetch to a PHP endpoint and want PHP to just output the _POST details.

```
e.preventDefault();

(async () =>
{
    const response = await fetch('form-api.php',
    {
        method: 'POST',        
        body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
    });
    const content = await response.json();
    console.log(content);
})();
```

form-api.php : `<?php echo json_encode($_POST) ?>`

But content is always []

I understand I can get it via :

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

But I want to know why $_POST is empty. It isn't when I use jQuery's AJAX like this.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url : "<?php echo CB_ABS_URI ?>ajax/change-bp-name.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",                
    data: { BPID: "<?php echo $BPID ?>", Name: $('#txt-bp-name').val() },
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if (data['Status'] == 'Error')
        {
            alert(data['Message']);
        }
        else
        {
            // alert(data['Message']);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well it depends how you used jQuery ajax. You'd have to show us. Presumably, you didn't send the data in JSON format with that one. That's the difference. Form-url-encoded data (which is what html forms send, and what jQuery sends by default) shows up in the $_POST array in PHP, whereas JSON must be retrieved by the method you've shown.

Comment: I have updated my post to show how I used jQuery AJAX. And I am retrieving the data in change-bp-name.php using $_POST.

Comment: Exactly as I said, you aren't sending JSON in the jQuery version

Comment: Try setting headers in the request? `headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },`

Comment: @rybo111 in the fetch code OP is already sending JSON and the server already successfully reads it. So the header won't change anything. It's unclear what the purpose of your suggestion is?

Comment: Also, try `var_dump($_POST);` when debugging.

Comment: @rybo111 $_POST will be empty in the fetch example because OP is sending JSON. They already know this. All they're asking is _why_ that happens, which I've already explained in the comments above. You seem to have missed the point of the question

Comment: @ADyson My understanding is the header will be sent as `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` by default.

Comment: Oh ! So `data: { BPID: "12", Name: "test" },` id not sending the data as JSON in the jQuery version ?

Comment: @rybo111 you mean in the fetch case? Yeah maybe it does but since JSON is text that's not a big problem - the PHP explicitly tries to decode it as JSON, and that works because it's JSON. Even adding that header will not cause the data to show up in $_POST because PHP just doesn't deal with JSON like that

Comment: No I meant in the jQuery case : `type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: { BPID: "1", Name: "John" },` - This doesn't actually send the data as JSON but as POST variables ?

Comment: @PlanBuildr sorry I misread and mistook you for rybo, apologies. No it doesn't. Read the documentation for $.ajax. the `dataType` option specifies what sort of data you expect in the response. It has nothing to with what you send. So that object you passed in will be converted to form-url-encoded format by jQuery before it sends the request. That's the default - again it's documented I believe. (Clearly it can't send a code object directly so it has to serialise it to _something_.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. All this time I was implementing jQuery's AJAX wrongly. I am in the process of getting rid of jQuery as much as possible and convert to vanially JS ES2017.

Comment: So sending JSON via jQuery would be something like : `data: JSON.stringify({ BPID: "123", Name: $('#txt-bp-name').val() }),`

Comment: Yes, and you should also set the content type option too